# XNA Falling through tiles after jumping

Tags: xna, tile

*I discovered a lot of new info since I posted this question so I have completely rewritten it:*

I have run into some problems while implementing gravity and jumping in my tile-based game.
Sometimes when my character lands between tiles after a jump, the characters falls through them.

The problem certainly is not that my speed is too high since my max speed is the same as my tile-size. Also, the problem does not occur after every time the character jumps. I can often make a jump, get to max velocity, and still land well. But sometimes the character just falls through.

My level exists of layers of tiles. Each layer has it's own collision-type. So every tile in the same layer, follows the same rules for collision.
In my current set-up all layers use per-pixel collision.

This is how I update the player coordinates
http://pastebin.com/qVc6gv6T

This is the class where I calculate my collissions.
http://pastebin.com/7GqrFih6

In the update I just do:

```
    controls.Update(player); 
    physicsEngine.HandleCollissions(levelManager, player);
```

I imagine that the problem could be because the player gets moved to another tile after collission. Collides with the other tile. But that doesn't count since the other tile already has been checked for collision?
Or could it be because I use foreach instead of for-loops?

Comment: I haven't looked at your code, But I'm assuming this may be the problem http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30458/platformer-starter-kit-collision-issues see the accepted answer.

Comment: The mobile object speed must be too high for collision decetion to process as intended, so you either change the maximum speed or extend the collision detection rules. You could also half the step and double update rate, but that is very resource costly and not a recommended solution.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
I am very busy right now, but I will certainly check out the platformer example this evening and keep you updated.
I dont think it can be the case that my object speed is too high though, since I cap the Y-velocity at 10, while my tilesize is 16;

Comment: I just lowered my max-falling speed and it seemed to help. So it was the object speed after all. My problem seems to be very similar to yours indeed Cyral. I will look more into it this evening.

Comment: So I played around in my game a little more, and I discovered that the bug still exists when using a max Y-velocity of 9. Which actually really did'nt surprise me. There is no reason why a maximum of 9 or 10 (or even 16) would cause problems while my tilesize is 16. After some more experimenting I discovered that the bug only happens when moving diagonally. So appearently the problem lies within my collision detection. Is there someone who can tell me directly what the problem causes, and how I should fix it?

Comment: Was it intentional that your player has both properties `VelocityY` and `Velocity.Y`, or was that a typo in copying your code?

Comment: well..... I need to set only the Y-component of the vector
and if I create a get and set method for the player.Velocity, I can set the whole vector, but not individual components. So I created a method VelocityY which I can use to set the Y component.....
But correct me if anything of this is wrong. I'm still a noob at c#.
And I too felt it is a very stupid way of doing, but I couldnt come up with something better.... I've read something about using UnitX and UnitY but I didn't quite get that.... So if you have a more elegant way of doing this, I will be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the error occurs after jumping.  So, your character falls toward a tile (has some positive `velocity.Y`) and hits it.  The collision code executes the `// the player comes FROM ABOVE and collides with the tile` block.  You run a loop that sets player velocity to zero and moves the player out of collision.  This loops calls a function using a term `tile` as an argument.  I assume you loop through a set of tiles in order to collide with more than a single square.  Am I right?

If I am, then the problem occurs after that first collision and correction.  Now your player has a `velocity.Y` of 0, but they are colliding with a new tile.  So in spite of your comment about the meaning of your else block, you may have more position changes happening:

```
if (player.Velocity.Y > 0) 
else // if (moveVector.Y < 0) // what you commented

else // if (moveVector.Y <= 0) // what your else really means
```

Now sometimes (only when you have slightly mis-alligned per-pixel collisions) you have course corrections happening the the wrong direction.  That would produce a fall-through effect.  You could try setting a break point in the `// the player comes FROM UNDER and collides with the tile` block, and then running the program in a scenario that shouldn't cause `player.WorldPositionY += 1;` to happen.  If it happens when it wasn't supposed to, then you have your culprit.

I am doing a lot of speculation here.  I think you should post *more* code so that we can know for sure.  But perhaps a paste bin would be appropriate place for it.

Comment: I know that the movevector could be equal to zero in my else-statement, but didn't i exclude that case in this part of the code in the handleCollission class?:
if (player.Velocity.X != 0)
            {}
if (player.Velocity.Y != 0)
            {}
I posted my entire control and collision class in a pastebin, could you please take another look at it?

Comment: I considered that, but that's why I speculated that you are looping through more than one tile.  If you are, then you'll exclude the error from happening only if the `Velocity.Y` is zero on the first tile.  If it becomes zero on the first tile, then the second tile is capable of the error.

Comment: Ah, I finally understand what you mean! I was focussing so hard on the code in the PERPIXEL COLLISION-region that I completely ignored the whole loop around it. I now use a bool to check wether a collission happened or not. If a collision did happen, i set the player.VelocityY to 0, after the whole loop. This seems to have resolved the problem since I havent encountered the bug since.
But i wonder, do you know by any chance a more elegant way to do this, instead of using a bool? Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: There's no magic answer; collisions are hard.  But there is lots of reading material available :)